# the name "xxx" does not exist in the current context when sending asp Literal name as a parameter to another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I´m trying to figure out why I´m getting this error when I try to send the name of asp:Literal as a parameter to a function in another class.

Certificate.aspx.cs:

```
login.DisplayLoginError(Company.Web.STSLogin.Common.Utils.LocalizeUtils.GetTranslation("login.unsuccessful", "Host", false), "attention", litMessageCertificate);
```

Login.aspx:

```
 <asp:Literal ID="litMessageCertificate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Login.aspx.cs:

```
    public void DisplayLoginError(string text, string messageType, Literal literal)
    {
        ClearTextBoxes(); //attention
        literal.Text = string.Format("<div id=\"customErrorPanel\" style=\"display : none\" class=\"message {1}\" >{0}</div>", text, messageType);
        string javaScriptFunction = "$(function () { $('#customErrorPanel').slideDown('fast'); });";
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "errorScript", javaScriptFunction, true);
    }
```

I´m getting the error: 
The name 'litMessageCertificate' does not exist in the current context.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: It seems that you forgot to include the Literal Control in your Certificate.aspx. Check the designer and see if it's in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to display a specific certificate error message in a literal control created for displaying only certificate error messages.  If making a generic error message literal in Login.aspx is not an option, you can pass in the error type as a string (or even an Integer)  to Login.aspx, instead of trying to pass a control between different aspx Pages.  Something like...

(certificate.aspx.cs)

```
login.DisplayLoginError(Company.Web.STSLogin.Common.Utils.LocalizeUtils.GetTranslation("login.unsuccessful", "Host", false), "attention", "ERROR_CERTIFICATE");
```

(login.aspx.cs)

```
public void DisplayLoginError(string text, string messageType, string errorType)
{
    ClearTextBoxes(); //attention

    if(errorType == "ERROR_CERTIFICATE"){
       litMessageCertificate.Text = string.Format("<div id=\"customErrorPanel\"style=\"display : none\" class=\"message {1}\" >{0}</div>", text, messageType);
      string javaScriptFunction = "$(function () {$('#customErrorPanel').slideDown('fast'); });";
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "errorScript",JavaScriptFunction, true);
    }
    else{//display a different error message in a different literal control}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you missing that literal control (with ID="litMessageCertificate") in Certificate.aspx? You are trying to reference non-existing object there.

The two pages don't know each other so you can't work with elements from Certificate.aspx in Login.aspx.cs and vice versa.